# How to do banded lat pulldowns on a half rack?

Tags: pull-ups, chin-ups

My [rack](https://treadmillfactory.ca/products/fit505-half-rack-with-pull-up-bar?currency=CAD&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&matchtype=&network=x&device=c&adposition=&keyword=&campaign=18936053233&adgroup=&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9MCnBhCYARIsAB1WQVVYCjkSFQfqGueiaVskfKotugQveuMTLHVDrNM45_Rs8wmg3aMpe10aAsuOEALw_wcB) is in a basement with a low ceiling, so unfortunately I can't do proper pull ups on it. I was wondering if I should be able to do banded lat pull downs using the pull up bar? The specifications don't mention them, but I figure if it would be strong enough to hold my bodyweight, this should be okay? What would be the best way to loop the bands, and would it be better in the middle or the edges?